# Given a start time and an interval in minutes, determine if current time is an interval

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, intervals

I'm working in VB.NET, but just looking for a formula that will give me the following:

Say I have a process that needs to be launched every x minutes between start time and end time. Every minute I need to determine if the process needs to be launched.

So if I have the following:

```
StartTime = 8:00:00 AM
EndTime = 11:00:00 PM
IntervalMinutes = 7
```

I have a timer set to fire every 1 minute. I need to determine if the current time is time to launch the process.

Currently I just use a loop that adds IntervalMinutes to StartTime and compares it to the current time and EndTime. If StartTime = CurrentTime then launch. If StartTime > End Time then exit loop. I know it's clunky but it works. However as it gets later in the day, it has to iterate through a lot more minutes. I know there has to be a formula for this but my brain is dead from searching and thinking.

Comment: why not use a `LastTimeFired` variable

Comment: Could you just fire the timer every IntervalMinutes instead of every minute?

Comment: The app is used to launch several processes each having various start times, end times, and intervals. This was the easiest way I could think of to handle that.

Comment: With an Interval of One Minute on your Timer, it would actually be possible to completely **miss** a "launch" time.  For instance, if your app started at 7:59:59 am, then the next Tick() should occur at 8:00:59 am...but the Tick() is only guaranteed to **Not** fire before your interval.  In actuality, it fires at some indeterminate period of time **after** that interval has passed.  If your system/application is busy, or through bad programming you've stopped your thread (possibly via a Sleep call), then the Tick() might not fire until 8:01:xx am and you will miss the launch.

Comment: It's definitely best to compute the Initial Date/Time that your event should occur at by repeatedly adding the interval to the start time until you get to some point in the future.  Then see if the current date/time is past that point to know if you need to launch.  Once that occurs you simply add the interval to the last known event date/time to get the next event date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pseudo modulus operation:

```
float tolerance = 0.0001f;

if((CurTime - StartTime) % IntervalMinutes <= tolerance)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and now that I see it, it's so easy. Kicking myself right now.

Comment: This is what I came up with in VB.NET:
`If ((Now - StartTime).TotalMinutes Mod IntervalMinutes) < 1 Then`

    `' Launch Process`

`End If`

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-calcualte all of the launch times between StartTime and EndTime on app start, put them in a List then each time the timer fires you only need to check if the current time == launchList[0]. If it does launch and remove that entry from the list.